# XSD Import NameSpaces

Tags: namespaces, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have a two xsd files "first.xsd" and "second.xsd".

Inside second.xsd, I want to refer to an element defined in first.xsd (with different namespace).
My second.xsd looks like:

```
<xs:schema ... xmlns:schema1="http://www.schema.org/schema1" targetNamespace "http://www.schema.org/schema2   ...  >
<xs:import namespace = "http://www.schema.org/schema1" schemaLocation = "first.xsd" />

<xs:element name = "complex1">
<xs:complexType>
.........
<xs:element ref="schema1:name2"/>
.........
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now I want to include and import second.xsd inside first.xsd
So I do the following in first.xsd:

```
<xs:schema ... xmlns:schema2="http://www.schema.org/schema2" targetNamespace "http://www.schema.org/schema1  ... >
<xs:import namespace="http://www.schema.org/schema2" schemaLocation="second.xsd">
<xs:element name = "name1"/>
<xs:element name = "name2"/>
<xs:element name = "name3"/>
```

Is this the right way to do since I not able to successfully validate the schema.
Is it a problem because of some cyclic namespace inclusion??
I'm using oxygen xml developer to validate the schema files and my first.xsd when validated says:
E[Xerces] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name to a(n) type definition component. (second.xsd)

But if I validate the second.xsd file separately it says schema valid.

In my actual case I have a very complex scenario so I've boiled it down to a simple example as shown above.
Could someone please help.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly valid (albeit debatable) to have these kind of circular dependencies; the reason why your schema set doesn't validate can't be it; you'll have to inspect the errors your schema processor generates and try to understand each one of them. It is generaly accepted that the best is to start with the first error message.

Your snippets are invalid since you're referencing an `element2` (in second.xsd) that you didn't list in **schema1**. This is the kind of thing that won't pass validation, so focus on them.

If you need help with understanding what the real issue is, start by updating your post with the actual error message.

Comment: thanks for ur response. The error which you pointed out is a typo. My mistake..  I've edited the code. The error which I get while validating the schema is: E[Xerces] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name to a(n) type definition component. (second.xsd) I'm using oxygen xml developer to validate the schema. But when I validate the second.xsd file, it says the schema is valid.

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to a type definition that cannot be found. Your interactive tool should allow you to somehow (double)click on the error and the cursor and to position your cursor where the error is. See what type is referring to; make sure that it is properly qualified, etc. If all seems in order, experiment by replacing all these offending types with a dummy, local one; in the end, it is either a typo or namespace qualifier you didn't get right, or a bug in a product. If all your efforts point to unexplainable, try to validate using another product.

Comment: I think this could be a bug in the tool that I'm using. Coz one of the tool reports an error, another tool reports a warning. But If I use xmllint to validate an xml file against this schema, it doesn't show any error. Anyways thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Hmm... this sounds very interesting. Since you're not mentioning what tools (beside libxml2)... if you can disclose at least privately what your XSDs are, I would be interested to have a look at them and your sample XML. You can contact me through the support address on my website. Alternatively, please download [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) and let me know what results you're getting with it. I am wondering if it is somehow related to how tools perform schema loading...